# How can I find the class inside button > span using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to change the icon when a user clicks a button, so first I need to find which icon the button has, determined by the name of the class.

I'm currently able to change the icon to something else, but when I try to *find* the class, it's not working.

I'm currently testing by showing an alert if the span has the right class, but it's not alerting. What am I doing wrong?

### HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fa fa-user-plus text-muted"></span>
</button>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '.follow', function(e) {
    var button = $(this);

    if(button.find('span').hasClass('fa-user-plus')) {
        alert();
        // won't alert!
    }
});
```

### Edit

The following code works; I'm able to change the icon to a spinner, so I know the button > span targeting is correct. I'm just not able to determine what class the span has.

```
button.find('span').removeClass('fa-user-plus').addClass('fa-spinner fa-spin');
```

Comment: Where is the button click event handler? Are you really missing that or just not showing it here?

Comment: @NawedKhan I've updated my question

Comment: What is ".follow" ? the button does not have a class named "follow".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting handle to the button correctly - $(this) gives you handle to the DOM, not the button. JQuery `$(this)` has different meanings in different contexts. You can get the button handle using an ID for example. See the following working snippet.

**Edit**:

I just read your comment. Accessing your button with the ID was just an example. You can access it with the CSS classes too. E.g. `$('.btn.btn-primary')`. See the edited snippet below.

```js
if($('.btn.btn-primary').find('span').hasClass('fa-user-plus')) {
    console.log("found");
    // won't alert!
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fa fa-user-plus text-muted"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: I can't target them by ID, as the same button with the same ID might appear a couple times on the page.

Comment: You should not have multiple elements with same ID. The ID is meant to be unique per page.

Comment: @NawedKhan Which is why I'm targeting them by class.

Comment: yes but where are you triggering the button click? "this" does'nt mean anything in your current context.

Comment: I was actually doing something really stupid earlier in the code: I was removing the `fa-user-plus` class, which is why it wasn't working \*facepalm\*. I'm giving you the credit because you answered it first. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the class "follow" to the button and use it as trigger:

**HTML:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary follow">
    <span class="fa fa-user-plus text-muted"></span>
</button>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.follow', function(e) {
    var button = $(this);

    if(button.find('span').hasClass('fa-user-plus')) {
        alert('hi');
        // won't alert!
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  var child = $(this.children)
  if(child.hasClass('fa-user-plus')) {
    child.removeClass('fa-user-plus').addClass('fa-spinner fa-spin');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Button
    <span class="fa fa-user-plus text-muted"></span>
</button>
```